# Why two targets linking differently using cmake?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, g++

I have this target that compiles ok.

```
#
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES
        8021QBG/*.h
        8021QBG/*.cpp
        )
add_library(8021qbg SHARED
        ${SOURCE_FILES}
        )
set_target_properties(8021qbg PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_CUSTOM " ")
set_target_properties(8021qbg PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS " ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_CUSTOM} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_COMMON}")
add_dependencies(8021qbg core )
target_link_libraries(8021qbg  -L${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(8021qbg  -L/home/user/protocol_so )
target_link_libraries(8021qbg  -L${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib64 )
target_link_libraries(8021qbg  -L${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(8021qbg protocol_common thread vip core m xml2)

target_include_directories(8021qbg PUBLIC
        8021QBG
        nte-encap
        )
```

and this that fails.

```
#
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES
        Agent/*.h
        Agent/*.cpp
        )
add_library(agent SHARED
        ${SOURCE_FILES}
        )
set_target_properties(agent PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_CUSTOM " ")
set_target_properties(agent PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS " ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_CUSTOM} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_COMMON}")
add_dependencies(agent core)
target_link_libraries(agent  -L${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(agent  -L/home/user/protocol_so )
target_link_libraries(agent  -L${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib64 )
target_link_libraries(agent  -L${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(agent protocol_common thread vip core xml2 pthread)
target_include_directories(agent PUBLIC
        Agent
        nte-encap
        )
```

Also these targets have the same flags:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_COMMON "-g -fpermissive -std=gnu89 -Wall -O0 -m64 -fPIC -DLINUX -DCPU_64 -DXSTREAM ")
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs -shared -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/protocol_so:/home/user/cmake_libs/lib64:libwifi")
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY
            "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> <CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CXX_FLAGS> <LANGUAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CREATE_CXX_FLAGS> <SONAME_FLAG><TARGET_SONAME> -o <TARGET> <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
endif()
```

This is linker stage

```
/usr/bin/g++  -fPIC -g -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs -shared -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/protocol_so:/home/user/cmake_libs/lib64:libwifi -shared -Wl,-soname,libagent.so -o libagent.so CMakeFiles/agent.dir/Agent/agent_common.cpp.o CMakeFiles/agent.dir/Agent/agent_main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/agent.dir/Agent/agent_client.cpp.o CMakeFiles/agent.dir/Agent/agent_cmd.cpp.o CMakeFiles/agent.dir/Agent/agent_go.cpp.o -L/home/user/cmake_libs/cmake-build-debug-rurem -L/home/user/protocol_so -L/home/user/cmake_libs/lib64 -L/home/user/cmake_libs -lprotocol_common -lthread -lvip libcore.so -lxml2 -lpthread -L/home/user/cmake_libs/lib64 -lprotocol_common -lthread -lvip -lcrypto -lglib-2.0 -lm -lxml2 -lpthread -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/cmake_libs/cmake-build-debug-rurem
```

This is error codes

```
/home/user/cmake_libs/Agent/agent_main.cpp:47: undefined reference to `agent_client_register'
/home/user/cmake_libs/Agent/agent_main.cpp:48: undefined reference to `agent_client_unregister'
/home/user/cmake_libs/Agent/agent_main.cpp:49: undefined reference to `agent_client_register_task'
/home/user/cmake_libs/Agent/agent_main.cpp:50: undefined reference to `agent_client_unregister_task'
```

Cmake compiles each *.cpp file to *.o object and than linker combine them in one *.so lib -> in the linker stage I got this error.

Sources located in "Agent" folder and I add it to the target 'agent'.

**UDP>**
simple makefile and GCC build this library.
makefile part:

```
libagent.so: ${wildcard Agent/*.[c,h]} libcore.so
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -shared -o $@ $(filter %.c,$^) $(IPATH) $(RPATH) $(TE_VIP) -lcore -lxml2 -lpthread
```

gcc command

```
gcc -g -Wall -O0 -m64 -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs  -fPIC -shared -o libagent.so  -Inte-include -Ixst_inc -Ixst_tls -L./lib64 -L./cmake-build-debug-rurem -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/protocol_so:/home/user/lib64:libwifi -DLINUX -DCPU_64 -DXSTREAM -lprotocol_common -lthread -lvip -lcore -lxml2 -lpthread
```

**UDP#2.**

on arm machine with gcc v9.1.0 it builds successfully via makefile.

on x86 machine with gcc v4.3.4 I have such undefined referencies.

this is compiling command

```
g++ -g -Wall -O0 -m64 -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs  -fPIC -shared -o 0libagent.so -Inte-include -Iinc -Itls -L/home/user/cmake_libs/lib64 -L/home/user/cmake_libs -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/protocol_so:/home/user/cmake_libs/lib64:libwifi -DLINUX -DCPU_64 -DXSTREAM -lprotocol_common -lthread -lvip -lcore -lxml2 -lpthread Agent/agent_main.cpp Agent/agent_cmd.cpp Agent/agent_client.cpp Agent/agent_go.cpp Agent/agent_common.cpp
```

This is piece of `agent_main.cpp` that causes errors:
[image]

This is function that defined in `agent_client.cpp` that causes undefined reference
[image]

**UPD#3**

nm says that definitions are in objects.

```
> nm CMakeFiles/agent.dir/Agent/agent_client.cpp.o
...
00000000000007e2 T _Z21agent_client_registeriP20_protocol_callback_t
0000000000000000 T _Z21agent_client_run_taskiPv
0000000000000033 T _Z22agent_client_do_actionPviS_S_
...
```

**x86 machine - SUSE 11 sp3 x64**

Why it fails? 
How to fix it?

Comment: So the linker is telling you that `agent_client_register` etc. have not been defined. Where do you think the definitions of those functions are?

Comment: @john, in ```Agent/agent_client.cpp```, this file compiled to object and object added by linker, but it doesn't work, and ```Agent/agent_client.h``` includes into ```Agent/agent_main.cpp``` with necessary declarations.

Comment: I wasn't asking about *declarations*, the problem is missing *definitions*. So same question again. Do you recognise the names of these functions? Are the definitions in code you have written (or downloaded or copied or whatever). There's no indication yet that anything isn't working, so far it just seems that you simply don't have the definitions for these functions. Unless you can tell me different.

Comment: @user3360601 what is the content of your cpp file `agent_client.cpp`?

Comment: @john, I updated post to make you see that makefile and gcc compile that binary, cmake doesn't

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, this is cmake problem, because source are compilable by makefile

Comment: So your cmake command has `libcore.so` where your gcc command has `-lcore`. I guess that's the issue.

Comment: @john, no, because 8021qbg lib, that I mentioned in the post, builds the same way.  Cmake replace this lib name from target dependencies. This is something another

Comment: @user3360601 OK, I still think it would help to know where the definitions of the missing functions are supposed to be. Otherwise it's guesswork.

Comment: @john, they are all in one folder and I see these definitions

Comment: @user3360601 I give up, I think you're being very obscure. This should be relatively easy, but you aren't supplying the necessary information.

Comment: @john, make and gcc can build this lib, so I am confused about cmake. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I may be missing something, but the second (makefile) example produces an empty `libagent.so` because your sources are all cpp files, not listed by `wildcard *.c`

Comment: @AlexCohn, o! I will check it tomorrow, I missed that!

Comment: Good point by Alex, I was just trying to look for the *.c files in the gcc line as well. You may want to insert print line just before the $(CC) line: `@echo $(filter %.c,$^) `. Then change that to `@echo $(filter %.cpp,$^)` and also change `${wildcard Agent/*.[c,h]}` -> `${wildcard Agent/*.[cpp,h]}`. Then I will assume that you get the same error. If so John's line of questioning comes back. Where are the missing functions defined? - i.e. where is the body of the code of function agent_client_register, i.e.: `agent_client_register(){...some-lines-of-code...}`, the linker can't find it.

Comment: @john, I updated  my question , please check it if you can help me. I see that this is not about cmake problem.

Comment: @code_fodder ,  I updated my question , please check it if you can help me. I see that this is not about cmake problem

Comment: @AlexCohn, I updated my question , please check it if you can help me. I see that this is not about cmake problem

Comment: @user3360601 it seems like this function `agent_client_register` is not getting compiled in the x86 machine. Can you add a line of code into that function that cuases an error like `bob;` just after `s_prot_id = prot_id;`. This should cause the compilation of that file to fail in **both** cases with `bob was not declared....` error. Can you confirm that both fail (arm gcc and x86 gcc)? I am wandering if that bit of code is #define'd out or somthing like that... So if they both give that warning then both are successfully trying to compile that function body.

Comment: @code_fodder, on both machines it founds 'bob' at compiling time. ```bob was not declared```, yes.

Comment: @code_fodder, I updated the post with check for object agent_client.cpp.o and it has function definition inside.

Comment: @code_fodder, x86 is SUSE 11 sp3 x64

Comment: I would try to declare `agent_client_register()` and the rest of them as **`extern "C"`** in **agent_client.h** and make sure this header is included in both  **agent_client.cpp** and **agent_main.cpp**.

Comment: @AlexCohn, strange, that on arm machine with gcc 9.1 it is unnecessary, BUT on x86 it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The main point was not in cmake, and even not in make commands. I think this is about gcc versions support. On x86 I have gcc v4.3.4.

As @AlexCohn said in the comments

> I would try to declare agent_client_register() and the rest of them as
>   extern "C" in agent_client.h and make sure this header is included in
>   both agent_client.cpp and agent_main.cpp

Comment: It seems that in one case, **gcc** is invoked instead of **g++**.